# Plotting a curve based on data points

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a set of data points from a history of events. One axis of the points corresponds to the number of years that have passed, the other axis is the number of events that have occurred. The frequency of events per year are only expected to increase over time, and at a rate that fits a curve. How do I determine the formula that plots the future of these data points based on that curve?

For example, say you have four points:

- (0,0)
- (1,0)
- (2,1)
- (3,4)

How would you plot a curve to approximate their growth?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you need this curve for. If you need approximate behavior over the entire interval, one approach would be to plot a [linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression), i.e. find the equation of the line which passes closest to all of the points.

If you need exact match of the given points, you want some interpolation scheme, perhaps *[linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation)* or *[cubic spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation)* for a higher degree of accuracy.